# not run JavaScript in php file

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp

I create code in which on click the radio button status will be changed as pending or complete and also change the value at database in cakephp.

But this not works sometimes.

Here is my code:
.ctp file where JavaScript code run

```
<div class="my-acc">
    <div class="my-acc-one">

        <div class="gap-top">&nbsp;</div>
        <?php echo $this->Form->create('ServiceSearch', array('id' => 'ServiceSearchForm', 'class' => 'regVerify', 'autocomplete' => 'off', 'novalidate' => 'novalidate', 'inputDefaults' => array('class' => '', 'div' => array('style' => 'width: 87%;margin-top: -22px;margin-left: 101px;')))); ?>
        <div>
            <div class="gap-top">&nbsp;</div>

            <div>
                <div class="gap-bottom gap-top"></div>
                <!-- -->
                <div class="sape">
                    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th width='20%'><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('ExpertUser.expert_id', __('Expert')); ?></th>
                                <th width='20%'><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('created', __('Created On')); ?></th>
                                <th width='15%'><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Consultation_Status', __('Status')); ?></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php if (empty($history)) { ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan='6' class='text-warning'><?php echo __('No history found.') ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                            <?php foreach ($history as $service):
                                if(!$service['Service']['price']) continue;
                                if($service['Service']['service_mode'] == 'email'){ ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <?php
                                        echo $this->Html->link($service['ExpertUser']['expert_id'], Router::url(array('controller' => 'experts', 'action' => 'profile', $service['ExpertUser']['expert_id']), true), array('escape' => false, 'target' => '_blank'));
                                        ?>
                                </td>
                                <td><?php echo showdatetime($service['Service']['created']); ?>&nbsp;</td>

                                <td>
                                    <div class="gap-bottom"></div>

                                    <p style="word-spacing: 50px;">
                                        <?php
                                            if ($service['Service']['status'] == 'pending' || $service['Service']['status'] == 'cancelled') {
                                            $selected = "pending";
                                            } else {
                                            $selected = "complete";
                                            }
                                            $options = array('pending' => 'pending', 'complete' => 'complete');
                                            $attributes = array('legend' => false, 'value' => $selected, 'class' => 'statusmy');
                                            echo $this->Form->create('ServiceStatus', array('id' => 'ServiceSatusForm','url' => array('controller' => 'experts', 'action' => "change_servicestatus", encrypt($service['Service']['id'])),'novalidate' => 'novalidate','inputDefaults' => array('class' => '', 'div' => array('class' => 'form-group'))));
                                            echo $this->Form->radio('status', $options, $attributes);
                                            echo $this->Form->end();
                                            ?>
                                    </p>
                                    <div class="gap-bottom">&nbsp;/div>
                                </td>
                            </tr> <?php } ?>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <!-- -->
                </div><!-- sape -->
                <div class="gap-bottom"></div>
                <div class="box-footer clearfix" align='right'>
                    <?php
                        echo $this->element('pagination');
                    ?><div class='clean'></div> <div class="gap-bottom"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="gap-bottom"></div>
            <!-- -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('input[type=radio][class=statusmy]').on('change', function () {
            $( "#ServiceSatusForm" ).submit();

        });
    </script>
   <style>
   </style>
```

Now in controller for this JavaScript here is method used

```
public function change_servicestatus($serviceId = null) {
    $this->layout = "ajax";
    if (isset($this->request->data['ServiceStatus']['status'])) {
        if ($this->request->data['ServiceStatus']['status'] == "pending") {
            $paid_status = "pending";
            $expert_status = 1 ;
        } else {
            $paid_status = "complete";
            $expert_status = 2 ;
        }
        $expert_id = $this->Session->read('Auth.ExpertData.Expert.id');
        $serviceId = decrypt($serviceId);
        $this->loadModel('Service');

        if ($serviceId) {
            $this->Service->id = $serviceId;

            $this->Service->recursive = -1;

            $service = $this->Service->findById($serviceId);
            if ($this->Service->saveField('status', $paid_status)) {
                $this->Message->setSuccess(__('Your status successfully change to ') . ucfirst($this->request->data['ServiceStatus']['status']) . '.', null, array('flashTitle' => 'Status Change successfully!'));
            } else {
                $this->Message->setWarning(__('Try again later!.'), null, array('flashTitle' => 'Try again later!'));
            }
        }
    } else {
        $this->Message->setWarning(__('Invalid Request!'), null);
    }
    $this->redirect($this->referer());
}
```

Comment: You have written selector in a wrong way ```$('input[type=radio][class=statusmy]')``` this should be something like ```$('input.statusmy[type="radio"]')```.

Comment: it is work at only second row ,for first and last rows java script is not working

Comment: Probably because you have used id ```ServiceSatusForm``` in your form and that is in a loop. So please check it once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class or the id of the desired input for the onclick like :

```
$('.statusmy').on('change', function () {
    $( "#ServiceSatusForm" ).submit();
});
```

or even give the input an ID.

Comment: it is work only second row ,for first and last rows java script is not working